# Standard ML :How to cycle through a list?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to write a program that cycle through a list n times.
Suppose that L = [a1, a2, ... , an]
What I am trying to achieve is [ai+1, a i+2, ... , an, a1, a2, ... , ai].

I referenced to a previous post about this exact problem. However, I am not sure how to obtain the output or [ai+1, a i+2, ... , an, a1, a2, ... , ai].

For the output: I tried 
-cycle([1,2,3,4], 5);

However the error that I am getting is that the operand and operator don't match

This is the code I found from the previous post:

```
fun cycle n i = 
if i = 0 then n
else cycle (tl n) (i-1) @ [hd(n)];
```

Comment: Your function is curried so you'll want to call it as `cycle [1,2,3,4] 5` instead of `cycle([1,2,3,4], 5)` (though you might notice a mistake when you do!).

Comment: Thanks man! Yeah, I'm getting the error "uncaught exception Empty." I will see if I can figure this one out.

Comment: You might find [this](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.Empty:EXN) documentation helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this using if-then-else:

```
fun cycle xs n =
    if n = 0
    then []
    else xs @ cycle xs (n - 1)
```

You might instead like to use pattern matching:

```
fun cycle xs 0 = []
  | cycle xs n = xs @ cycle xs (n - 1)
```

But the most elegant solution, I think, is using higher-order functions:

```
fun cycle xs n =
    List.concat (List.tabulate (n, fn _ => xs))
```

---

A slightly harder task is how to write a `cycle` for lazy lists that cycles infinitely...

```
datatype 'a lazylist = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazylist) | Nil

fun fromList [] = Nil
  | fromList (x::xs) = Cons (x, fn () => fromList xs)

fun take 0 _ = []
  | take _ Nil = []
  | take n (Cons (x, tail)) = x :: take (n - 1) (tail ())

local
  fun append' (Nil, ys) = ys
    | append' (Cons (x, xtail), ys) =
        Cons (x, fn () => append' (xtail (), ys))
in
  fun append (xs, Nil) = xs
    | append (xs, ys) = append' (xs, ys)
end

fun cycle xs = ...
```

where `take 5 (cycle (fromList [1,2])) = [1,2,1,2,1]`.